# Can you solve a second order ODE of this kind, without assuming some ansatz?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

An ODE of the form: $\frac{1}{f}\frac{df}{dx}=\alpha$ can be solved via integration "directly". But now, let's say you have: $\frac{1}{f}\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}=\alpha$. Now you can integrate twice to get $f$, but then it equals:

$$f=\int\left(\int f\alpha \ dx \right) \ dx$$

But this is simply "solving by quadrature" or in other words arriving at an integral equation which is equally complicated. Now, assuming an exponential solutrion (for example) would work. But can you find a solution without making a hypothesis?

Comment: You mean specifically for this particular second-order ODE with $\alpha$ a constant? If so, _yes_. (Separately, rewriting an ODE as an integral equation is not, I think, what's generally meant by _solving by quadrature_.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transform it to a system of two equations of lesser degree

$f''-\alpha f=\underbrace{(f'-\sqrt{\alpha}f)\ '}_{u'}+\sqrt{\alpha}\underbrace{(f'-\sqrt{\alpha}f)}_u=0$

leads to $\begin{cases}u'+\sqrt{\alpha}\ u=0\\f'-\sqrt{\alpha}\ f=u\end{cases}\quad$ which you know how to solve using direct integration.

Answer (score 1):

There's a sneaky trick you can use:

$$\begin{eqnarray} \frac{d^2 f}{dx^2} & = & \frac{d(f')}{dx} \\
& = & \frac{d(f')}{df} \frac{df}{dx} \\
& = & \frac{d(f')}{df} f' \\
& = & \frac{1}{2} \frac{d(f'^2)}{df} \end{eqnarray}$$

So then applying that to the DE gives

$$\begin{eqnarray} \frac{1}{f} \frac{d^2 f}{dx^2} & = & \alpha \\
\frac{1}{2f} \frac{d(f'^2)}{df} & = & \alpha \\
\int d(f'^2) & = & 2 \alpha \int f\ df \\
f'^2 & = & \alpha f^2 + C_1 \end{eqnarray}$$

You can then rearrange and integrate, and although the solutions you get from that won't look exactly like the ones you might get from other methods you can prove that they're the same.